# How to merge and split again thousands of text files?

Tags: python, text, merge, filesplitting

I have thousands of .txt files. These text files include one string. (Every file has different string.)

I want to edit these strings but i don't want to manually open each file one-by-one for editing. So i want to merge all these files into a single .txt file and after my editing done, i want to seperate/split them again with the same file names they were owned before i merged.

For example;

i have these text files.

**lorem.txt (hi, this is an example line.)**

**ipsum.txt (hi, this is another line.)**

**merol123.txt (hi, just another line.)**

*

> merged.txt >>> edited and ready to split again. >> result needs to be
>   like this;

*

**lorem.txt (hi, this is edited line.)**

**ipsum.txt (another edited line.)**

**merol123.txt (another edited line. number 4847887)**

> Note: Sentences inside brackets represents string inside txt file.

Is it possible? I am waiting your helps, thanks!

Comment: If you simply merge all of them to one file without any additional data, how will you possibly be able to split them back to original names?

Comment: Yes i need to store original file name for it too, but i don't know how to do it. It will not be a problem for me. It can store data too!

Comment: By the way you are trying to go about this, it will be much (much!) easier, opening the files one by one, changing what you want, and saving all that merging-splitting stuff. I mean, you're saying *i don't want to manually open each file one-by-one for editing* but in order to merge and split you will have to open each twice...

Comment: @ipaleka's answer solved my problem. Thanks to him-her again.

Comment: Yes @ipaleka 's solution is beautiful. But I have a feeling that if you run timing test with that solution and simply working on each file, the latter will be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>First of all, I assumed you've not repeated your strings correctly (like "hi, this is an example line." != "hi, this is edited line.") by mistake, not on purpose (that I can't figure out).</strike>

I named the accumulative file `common.doc` to distinct from the other `.txt` files in the target directory. Also, this example code implies all the files are in the same directory.

```
# merging.py
import os
import glob

with open("common.doc", "w") as common:
    for txt in glob.glob("./*.txt"):
        with open(txt, "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
        common.write("{} ({})\n".format(os.path.basename(txt), content))
```

And after `common.doc` editing:

```
# splitting.py
with open("common.doc", "r") as common:
    for line in common:
        name = line[:line.find(" (")]
        text = line[line.find(" (")+2:line.rfind(")")]
        with open(name, "w") as f:
            f.write(text)
```

And a solution for multiline text (merging stays with `.strip()` removed on content writing), not suitable for hundreds of thousands of files tho...

```
# splitting2.py
with open("common.doc", "r") as common:
    everything = common.read()
elements = everything.split(")")
for elem in elements:
    name = elem[:elem.find(" (")].strip()
    text = elem[elem.find(" (")+2:]
    if name:
        with open(name, "w") as f:
            f.write(text)
```

Comment: To read better this comment: http://prntscr.com/oecu48

Thank you but how it will understand to which name the text file be?

Let's say the text file named 999.txt has a string like "asd123" and after the merge that string is at 6987th line in the common.doc.
I changed that string to "678qwe"
How code will know it needs to create that line as "999.txt" again?

btw: yes i will change all strings in each file. they will not stay same. maybe they will stay same in few files.

Comment: So i think, it needs to store original file name data too. Otherwise how can it understand how to create file name of that string.

Comment: EDIT: Working flawless! Thank you. If you read a comment from me about an error few minutes ago it was not your fault, i made a mistake about files. I fixed it now, and working good! Thank you again. I marked as correct answer

Comment: By the way, if the file has more than 1 line. Do you have a solution for that? Some files have "blank" lines. They dont have any characters. But i want to make sure i will leave it like it was before. It might harm my project even they are blank lines.

Comment: I have 25.000 files and it's working, thank you again